# Issue with button with image not showing in Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, wpf

i've made an application in WPF with custom minimize, maximize and close buttons. In Windows 10 all works fine but when i install the application on an Windows 2012 server the Images in the button are gone. When you click on the the place where the buttons ment to be the actions work fine only no Images.

When i resize the app the images appear to be stuk in the middel of the application. when i resize smaller the image stay in the button when i go bigger the images leave the buttons.

What is going on. Is there anyone who had the same issue?

```
            <Button x:Name="MinimizeButton" Padding="3" Width="25" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,55,0" Click="MinimizeButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="Images/minimizeIconRed.png" Height="23" Width="23"/>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="MaximizeButton" Padding="4" Width="25" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,30,0" Click="MaximizeButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="Images/maximizeIconRed.png" Height="23" Width="23"/>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <Button Width="25" Padding="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click_1" Grid.Column="1" Background="{x:Null}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="Images/closeIconRed.png" Height="23" Width="23"/>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: What happens if you place the ContentPresenter before (under) the image?

Comment: @NeilB The Image would overlay the ContentPresenter, the Content would hence not be visible??

Comment: The ContentPresenter is not the issue. I've even treid it without. stil te same issue. It is like the images are not part of the button en are hidden behind the Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the default LowQuality BitmapScalingMode ([default changed in 4.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf3d/2009/06/24/whats-new-in-graphics-for-4-0-beta-1/))

Changing to `RenderOptions.BitmapScaling="HighQuality"` seemed to fix the issue for me.

```
<Button x:Name="MinimizeButton" Padding="3" Width="25" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,55,0" Click="MinimizeButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Images/minimizeIconRed.png" Height="23" Width="23" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
<Button x:Name="MaximizeButton" Padding="4" Width="25" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,30,0" Click="MaximizeButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Images/maximizeIconRed.png" Height="23" Width="23" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
<Button Width="25" Padding="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click_1" Grid.Column="1" Background="{x:Null}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Images/closeIconRed.png" Height="23" Width="23" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```